# Jetty gives an error after an edit to the project

Tags: java, jetty, noclassdeffounderror

I was developing my web application, which runs on jetty, and I didn't have any problem; but added a POST web service I got this error when I run the project:

```
    013-06-17 12:08:19.398:INFO::jetty-6.1.26
2013-06-17 12:08:19.437:INFO::Extract /Users/carlo/Projects/datalift/wrapper/dist/DataLift.app/Contents/Resources/webapps/openrdf-sesame.war to /Users/carlo/Library/Caches/DataLift/webapps/openrdf-sesame/webapp
2013-06-17 12:08:20.101:INFO:/openrdf-sesame:Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'openrdf-http-server'
2013-06-17 12:08:20.678:INFO::Extract /Users/carlo/Projects/datalift/wrapper/dist/DataLift.app/Contents/Resources/webapps/datalift.war to /Users/carlo/Library/Caches/DataLift/webapps/datalift/webapp
2013-06-17 12:08:20.706:WARN::failed org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext@6e7616ad{/datalift,/Users/carlo/Projects/datalift/wrapper/dist/DataLift.app/Contents/Resources/webapps/datalift.war}: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/datalift/fwk/log/web/LogServletContextListener
2013-06-17 12:08:20.707:WARN::failed HandlerCollection@acaf083: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/datalift/fwk/log/web/LogServletContextListener
2013-06-17 12:08:20.707:WARN::Error starting handlers
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/datalift/fwk/log/web/LogServletContextListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:392)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.loadClass(ContextHandler.java:1102)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.initListener(WebXmlConfiguration.java:630)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.initWebXmlElement(WebXmlConfiguration.java:368)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.initialize(WebXmlConfiguration.java:289)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configure(WebXmlConfiguration.java:222)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configureWebApp(WebXmlConfiguration.java:180)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1279)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.datalift.wrapper.Wrapper.main(Wrapper.java:320)
2013-06-17 12:08:20.712:INFO::Started SocketConnector@localhost:9091
```

And despite I removed that method, and tried to reconfigure and re-run the application I always get this error. What is wrong? How could I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- you are using jetty6 which is over a 150 releases old while I write this.  jetty9 is currently...current

2- Since it is not a ClassNotFoundException, I wonder if you have multiple instances of that class available in the classloader, that often results in a NoClassDefFound. Perhaps you have multiple versions in your webapp?  Check if you have a couple under jetty.home/lib (maybe lib/ext) as with the right command line options you could be exposing that to the normally isolated webapp classloader.  This is generally a problem when you have the parentLoaderPriority to true as well on your WebAppContext, should you have fiddled with that.

[edit] you might be using the maven plugin, in which case again make sure you do not have multiple instances of that class being loaded by the plugin, either through dependencies that might have different groupId:artifact:versions or multiple versions floating around under target if that is your project structure (as can be seen when you update and recompile after a release